# Insert block above comments in node

Tags: blocks, theming

How to display block in node above comments. What i have tried is: 
create region - `regions[above_comments] = Above comments` after in *template.php* i have added this to `THEME_preprocess_node`

```
$variables['above_comments'] = theme('blocks', 'above_comments');
```

and in my node.tpl.php i have added this below `print render($content);`

```
<?php if ($above_comments): ?>
   <?php print $above_comments; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Added my content to this region, but its still empty, `dpm($variables['above_comments'])` - - is empty.
What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure commets are `open` for content type.

Comment: Is this Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: its drupal7 block, this block is `open` for my content type yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`theme_blocks()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_blocks/6) was only available for Drupal 5 & 6, which is why your code isn't working.

The D7 equivalent is [`block_get_blocks_by_region()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_get_blocks_by_region/7), e.g.:

```
$variables['above_comments'] = drupal_render(block_get_blocks_by_region('above_comments'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 7: [Commentsblock](http://drupal.org/project/commentsblock) or even in 6: [Comment block](http://drupal.org/project/commentblock)

Separate comment from node, then place your block above of comment block

Comment: thank you but i need to manage to do this without any modules. its possible, but i am not sure how to do it

Answer (score -3):

See [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7)

Check where it prints `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>`

Just render your region before `<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>`

Comment: You can't just render regions in node.tpl.php like that; at that point in the process, that template will have no clue what you're trying to reference. Clive's is the best answer.