# Position Block Below Content but Above Editor

Tags: blocks, theming

I have created a block for a horizontal ad. I positioned it in the Content region and as you know I can display it either above the content or below everything. However, I would like it positioned above the editor (or comments area), not above it all.

[I have found this pots](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52360/insert-block-above-comments-in-node) but I am using an [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega)-based theme and I see under the all/themes/omega/templates folder that there are "region.tpl" files so I assume here is where I add it, not in a node.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Omega based themes still allow for custom regions and various *.tpl.php files. There is probably a `node.tpl.php` theme file in the base theme thats inherited by the subtheme your using.

The code doesnt go in the tpl.php file it goes in the preprocess function:

> How to display block in node above comments. What i have tried is:
>   create region - regions[above_comments] = Above comments after in
>   template.php i have added this to THEME_preprocess_node

You then output the correct `block` within the specific `region` of the theme. In the linked page they created a region called `Above comments` in their theme. They set a block to that region using the Blocks Admin UI and rendered it using `block_get_blocks_by_region` using the theme preprocess function.

Comment: I opened preprocess-region.inc and this is what I see:

`<?php

if (in_array($vars['elements']['#region'], array('user_second', 'menu'))) {
  $theme = alpha_get_theme();
  switch ($vars['elements']['#region']) {
    case 'user_second':
   $vars['secondary_menu'] = $theme->page['secondary_menu'];
   break;
 
 case 'menu':
   if (isset($theme->page['dropdown_menu'])) {
    $vars['dropdown_menu'] = $theme->page['dropdown_menu'];
   }
   break;
  }
}`

@tenken